# SELECT a single field by ordered value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following two tables:

```
student_id  score   date
-------------------------
1           10      05-01-2013
2           100     05-15-2013
2           60      05-01-2012
2           95      05-14-2013
3           15      05-01-2011
3           40      05-01-2012


class_id        student_id
----------------------------
1               1
1               2
2               3
```

I want to get unique class_ids where the score is above a certain threshold for at least one student, ordered by the latest score.

So for instance, if I wanted to get a list of classes where the score was > 80, i would get class_id 1 as a result, since student 2's latest score was above > 80.

How would I go about this in t-sql?

Comment: Use `Select Distinct` and `Inner join`. This is just a basic of T-SQL query

Comment: This is an odd design. What is the context of the student scores? For example, student 2 has three scores but to what class do the scores apply?

Comment: Doan: It is not this simple, as I need to ignore old scores. I need to incorporate only the scores which have the most recent date.

Comment: Thomas: the top table is an historical one meant to keep a record of all scores achieved, by date. The bottom table is simply a lookup table.

Comment: What version of SQL Server, please?

Comment: this is in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit based on your date requirement, then you could use `row_number()` to get the result:

```
select c.class_id
from class_student c
inner join
(
  select student_id,
    score,
    date,
    row_number() over(partition by student_id order by date desc) rn
  from student_score
) s
  on c.student_id = s.student_id
where s.rn = 1
  and s.score >80;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09791/1)

Or you can use a `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
select c.class_id
from class_student c
where exists (select 1
              from student_score s
              where c.student_id = s.student_id
                and s.score > 80
                and s.[date] = (select max(date)
                                from student_score s1
                                where s.student_id = s1.student_id));
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09791/4)

Comment: The first query did the trick! Thank you; this was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking for this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t2.[class_ID]
FROM
    t1
JOIN t2
    ON t2.[student_id] = t1.[student_id]
WHERE
    t1.[score] > 80
```

Comment: Sort of, I need it to be by date as well. So in the example I provided, if student 2's latest score was 40, he would not be a part of the result regardless of the fact that he had an 80 at some point

Comment: @user984444 see bluefeet's answer, it meets your needs as I understand them.

Comment: I think the original post had all the information you needed to understand the requirements, especially the part about "since student 2's latest score was above > 80."

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(class_id) from table2 where student_id in
(select distinct(student_id) from table1 where score > thresholdScore)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CS.Class_ID
FROM
   dbo.ClassStudent CS
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.StudentScore S
      WHERE CS.Student_ID = S.Student_ID
      ORDER BY S.Date DESC
   ) L
WHERE
   L.Score > 80
;
```

And here's another way:

```
WITH LastScore AS (
   SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
   FROM dbo.StudentScore
   ORDER BY Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_ID ORDER BY Date DESC)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
   CS.Class_ID
FROM
   dbo.ClassStudent CS
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM LastScore L
      WHERE
         CS.Student_ID = L.Student_ID
         AND L.Score > 80
   )
;
```

Depending on the data and the indexes, these two queries could have very different performance characteristics. It is worth trying several to see if one stands out as superior to the others.

It seems like there could be some version of the query where the engine would stop looking as soon as it finds just one student with the requisite score, but I am not sure at this moment how to accomplish that.